# Javascript innerHTML is not getting updated

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to update the innerHTML of following script

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
<div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
Your submission was successful.
<button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

I have tried following

```html
var cls =document.getElementById("global-alert-queue").getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].innerHTML = "Change Text";
```

But its not working.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/mckgxkr1/1/ - looks fine

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: make sure the document is ready

Comment: No. But if i try to print cls its printing properly.

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kg3cc4gw/3/

Comment: Is your id "global-alert-queue" is unique to your HTML page?

Comment: HOW is the code being triggered? You need to show it in a working example.

Comment: your example works - what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Yes global-alert-queue is unique in HTML. 
Expected is "Change Text" should replace "Your submission was successful."

Comment: Yeah it was working but its removing the button class. Can i change the text without removing the button class ?

Answer (score 1):

See the comments inline:

```
// Run when document is completely rendered and is ready to be manipulated 
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
    document.querySelector("#global-alert-queue .animate-in").innerHTML = "Change Text";
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/kg3cc4gw/3/

**querySelector**

> Returns the first element within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that matches the specified group of selectors.

More on `querySelector`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector

Answer (score 0):

seems like it is working correctly. Maybe you should move your script below the HTML. or check for document ready.

```js
 var cls =document.getElementById("global-alert-queue").getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].innerHTML = "Change Text";
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
<div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
Your submission was successful.
<button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yeah it was working but its removing the button class. Can i change the text without removing the button class ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `var cls=...`. Here's a working [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kxaj994x/).

Comment: Yeah it was working but its removing the button class. Can i change the text without removing the button class ?

Answer (score 0):

you can add button as string with Text then you get your Output [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b1k0qcLu/)
Html

```js
function changeText() {

  var cls = document.getElementById("global-alert-queue").getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].innerHTML = 'Change Text <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button" onclick="changeText()">Change</button>';
}
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
  <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
    Your submission was successful.
    <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button" onclick="changeText()">Change</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your updated requirement(`Expected is "Change Text" should replace "Your submission was successful."`)

You cannot update the inner html of `animate-in` as it will remove the button element also.

So one solution will be is to update only the first child of `animate-in` which is the text node containing the value like

```
document.querySelector("#global-alert-queue .animate-in").firstChild.nodeValue = "Change Text";
```

Another way is to update the markup to wrap the text in another element like

```js
document.querySelector("#global-alert-queue .animate-in > span").innerHTML = "Change Text";
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
  <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
    <span>Your submission was successful.</span>
    <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```