# Javascript modify the text inside the div class

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I am trying to update the " Your submission was successful."of following script, with following javascript code :

```js
var cls = document.getElementById("global-alert-queue").getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].innerHTML = "Change Text";
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
  <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
    Your submission was successful.
    <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Its replacing the text along with button class. Can i replace only the text ?

Comment: I've already answered this on your other question   http://stackoverflow.com/a/30845787/2025923

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/b1k0qcLu/

Answer (score 2):

Just do this:

**Html**

```
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
    <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
        Your submission was successful.
        <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button" onClick="changeText()">Change</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
function changeText() {
    document.getElementsByClassName("animate-in")[0].firstChild.nodeValue = "Change Text";
}
```

Here the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/v9fmzLpx/

Answer (score 2):

The problem with updating inner html of `animate-in` is there is a button element inside that element which you don't want to change.

So you need to access the first child of animate-in which is the text node to be updated.

```js
document.querySelector("#global-alert-queue .animate-in").firstChild.nodeValue = "Change Text";
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
  <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
    Your submission was successful.
    <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Or a better solution will be to wrap the text in another element and update that element like

```js
document.querySelector("#global-alert-queue .animate-in > span").innerHTML = "Change Text";
```

```html
<div id="global-alert-queue" class="layout-wrapper">
  <div class="alert success animate-in" role="alert">
    <span>Your submission was successful.</span>
    <button id="dismiss-alert" class="dismiss" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```